# Deploy Databricks with VNETinjection using Terraform via Github actions

Tags: github-actions, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to deploy a ADB workspace with vnet injection using Terraform via github actions.

I was using the existing terraform code [HERE](https://github.com/databricks/terraform-databricks-examples/tree/main/examples/adb-vnet-injection).

When I try to deploy this using a github actions workflow, I get the following error:

```
Error: default auth: cannot configure default credentials. Config: azure_client_secret=***, azure_client_id=***, azure_tenant_id=***. Env: ARM_CLIENT_SECRET, ARM_CLIENT_ID, ARM_TENANT_ID
```

My github action workflow looks like this:

```
name: Deploy ADB with VNET injection

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  terraform:
    name: 'Deploy Terraform with remote state'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID }}             
      ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET }}
      ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
      ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID }} 

    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
        working-directory: adb_vnetinjection

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: 'Terraform init' 
        id: init                                   
        run: |                                     
          terraform init        
              
      - name: 'Terraform plan'                                   
        id: plan                                   
        run: |                                     
          terraform plan                 
                                    
      - name: 'Terraform apply' 
        id: apply            
        run: |    
          terraform apply -auto-approve
```

I've verified that the Service principal is the contributor to the subscription as I was able to use the same credentials and same workflow to deploy a normal databricks workspace. However I think, the terraform which I'm using is attempting to create a workspace and then create a cluster within the workspace.
Is there some additional permissions which I need to assign to the Service principal to get this to work? Obviously I cannot assign the SPN as a admin to the workspace as the workspace is being created by the Terraform script itself.
Any help  would be appreciated.

**#Update :**

So after running some more tests, I found that the problem was when the workspace.tf file tries to call the module to create the cluster. I just removed the concept of cluster creation and brought that entire code into the workspace.tf file and the entire script ran fine from githuba actions.
So I think the main question is, how do I pass the below 4 environment variables from the main terraform script to a module to it can the module can authenticate correctly with Azure/databricks workspace?

```
ARM_CLIENT_ID:              
ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: 
ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID:
ARM_TENANT_ID:
```

Comment: Does this help? It seems inconclusive https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76016279/terraform-databricks-cannot-configure-default-credentials. Does it work _without_ VNET injection? Do Terraform logs (or even Azure provisioning logs) give you any clue what step it was up to?

Comment: Thanks but I had already seen this. The answer says that the databricks provider uses the same Env authentication Env variables as Azurerm. This is what the cloned github repo already has. However this still doesn't work. Am not sure if I'm missing some extra permissions.